# perl get last N times of matches within a line

Tags: regex, perl

I want to get N+1 parts separately from single line string $a1, where the first part of $a1 difintely contains characters, may contain digits, comma, single space or consecutive multiple spaces.
while for parts2 to partN+1 contains only numbers.

```
#       (part1)                     (part2)   (part3)  (part4)
my $a1=' adf  baifdhi ads 1882,  3   123       456     7';

$a1 =~ /^(.*)(\s+\d+){$N}$/;
$part1 = $1; (no problem here)
```

But how can I get the numbers for part2 to partN? It seems $2 gives me only the last occurance of match.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A capture group that is repeated `(...){5}` will only return the last value.

To get all the values, use a capture group around the repeated expression `((?:...){5})`, and then `split`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#        (part1)                     (part2)   (part3)  (part4)
my $a1 = ' adf  baifdhi ads 1882,  3   123       456     7';
my $N  = 3;

if ($a1 =~ /^(.*)((?:\s+\d+){$N})$/) {
    my $part1 = $1;
    my @numbers = split ' ', $2;

    use Data::Dump;
    dd $part1;
    dd @numbers;
}
```

Outputs:

```
" adf  baifdhi ads 1882,  3  "
(123, 456, 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split off the fields at the end that contain only decimal digits then you can do it all using `split`. Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $a1 = ' adf  baifdhi ads 1882,  3   123       456     7';

my @fields = split /\s+(?=[\d\s]+\z)/, $a1;

print "$_\n" for @fields;
```

**output**

```
 adf  baifdhi ads 1882,
3
123
456
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you use multiple matches in a capture group, you only capture that last iteration of the capture.

Example of `^(.*)(\s+\d+){3}$` the second caputure group will be `'   7'`

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bK0rT1/1)

Notice the note in Regex101:

> Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration.
>   **Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all
>   iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not
>   interested in the data**

If you now put this modification of `^(.*)((?:\s+\d+){3})$` you capture `" 123       456     7"` as the second capturing group by putting the repeating pattern in a non capture group `(?:\s+\d+){3}` and then putting that entire group into a capture group of `((?:\s+\d+){3})`

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bK0rT1/2)

So your code is *almost* right:

```
use Data::Dump;

#       (part1)                     (part2)   (part3)  (part4)
my $a1=' adf  baifdhi ads 1882,  3   123       456     7';
my $N=3;

$a1 =~ /^(.*)((?:\s+\d+){$N})$/;

dd $1;
# " adf  baifdhi ads 1882,  3  "
dd $2;
# " 123       456     7"
```

You can also split the two parts:

```
my ($first, $second)=(split /^(.*)((?:\s+\d+){$N})$/, $a1)[-2,-1];

if ($first && $second){
    print "$first\n$second";
}
```